# CGI Error - Permission denied

Tags: perl, apache, webserver, cgi

I have a perl webapp that works fine on the server but not on my local machine.

Apache logs show (among other errors):

```
Permission denied at /home/mywebapp/dev/www/index.cgi line 318.
End of script output before headers: index.cgi
```

Line `318` in index.cgi:

```
our @gr;
eval('require Groups;');
#close STDERR; <<<< commented
open STDERR, '>1' or die $!;  <<<< line 318
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Your comment `// commented` is not a comment in perl. Only a hash sign `#` is a comment. See [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Comments)

Comment: yes, its not in the file, I just put it here for clarity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

STDERR shouldn't be '>1' - it should be '>&1'. The way it's written now, your script will try to create a file called 1 in a directory where the web server user doesn't have write permission.

Comment: This, or he can just chmod the perl file even though I highly doubt he wants to create files on that directory.

Comment: Um, no. Chmoding the perl file will have no effect on its ability to create files in a given directory. Also, the point of redirecting STDERR to STDOUT is to get the error messages to the web page instead of in the logs.